# Dynamically change color of a VBO in Opengl

Tags: c#, opengl, shader, vbo, shading

I am developing a tilemapping game engine and I have a CPU handled lighting like minecraft not smooth lightning (on the left):

[image: not smooth/smooth]

I need to change the color of each tile when light updates or when light is updated. Right now, I am using this to to color and translate the vbo:

```
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tile.states[tile.animationstate]);
GL.PushMatrix();
GL.Translate(position.X, position.Y, 0);
GL.Color3(col);
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, tile.vbo);
GL.VertexPointer(2, VertexPointerType.Float, Vertex.SizeInBytes, 0);
GL.TexCoordPointer(2, TexCoordPointerType.Float, Vertex.SizeInBytes, Vector2.SizeInBytes);          
GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Quads, 0, 4);
GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);
GL.PopMatrix();
```

`GL.Color3` (equivalent to `glColor3f`) and the game performance is getting from 1000 fps to 830 fps. How can I change the color of the tiles dynamically?

There isn't a vbo for each tile of the map. Each tile image has it's vbo and texture and the map is an int[,]. The value of the map in the location is used in a array of tiles:

```
Render(map.tiles[map.level[x, y]]);
```

I already tried using `GL.SubBufferData` but doing it 4 times each drawcall for rendering a tile decreased the fps to 74. I would not like to use `GL.ColorPointer` because there isn't a vbo for each tile being drawn.

Comment: Store a color with each vertex and update the vertex buffer.  Or have the vertex shader sample a texture to get the color and update the texture.  Or just compute the color in the shader.  What kind of advice beyond this are you looking for?

Comment: something like glColor3 without 200fps of performance loss. I tried programs and shaders but performance was even worse

Comment: The goal is to minimize driver calls, so programs and shaders *is* the way to go.  If things got worse it could be because you did something wrong.  It all depends how often this code gets executed and how much dynamic data you have.

Comment: the code is ran each frame

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are relying on the VBO for position information, but you are relying on the fixed-function pipeline to get per-vertex color information.  I wonder if it's the mixed approach that causes trouble.  To confirm: either add color information to the vertices via VBO (doesn't matter how many VBO streams you use); or put the color as a uniform in your shader (preferred - but you've expressed resistance to this).

Comment: shader performance was worse than glcolor3

Comment: Which OpenGL library for C# are you using?  OpenGL.net?  SharpGL?  OpenTK?

Comment: The obvious thing is that you are only drawing 4 indices.  That's presumably only one tile.  You should draw all your tiles with a single DrawArrays call.

Comment: I am using OpenTK